# Have to run my script twice?

Tags: php, bash, phpunit

I wrote a script that walks through each directory, while ignoring some, and does a `composer install`, `phpunit` and should work, for the most part it does - When i run it a second time ...

The issue is the `phpunit` command. The script comes to that command and prints out:

```
...
+ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
+ phpunit
PHPUnit 4.6.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Usage: phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [options] <directory>
...
```

When I run it a second time I get:

```
...
+ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
+ phpunit
PHPUnit 4.6.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from /vagrant/Freya/Form/phpunit.xml

...............................................................

Time: 647 ms, Memory: 15.25Mb

OK (63 tests, 63 assertions)
...
```

I should not have to run the script twice. The goal of the script is to say: Do you have a vendor directory? no, ok do a `composer install` and run `phpunit` If we encounter a directory that has a `routes-test.sh` file we then do some other things, but the concept is still the same at the end of the day.

So, with the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eux

function run_tests() {
  if [[ -f "composer.json" ]]; then
    if [[ -d "vendor" ]]; then
      composer update
      phpunit
      cd ../
    else
      composer install
      phpunit
      cd ../
    fi
  fi
}

function wordpress_routes() {
  cd ../../
  if [[ -d "trunk" ]]; then
    cd trunk
    if [[ -f "wp-tests-config.php" ]]; then
      continue
    else
      cd ../Freya/Routes/
      cp wp-tests-config.php ../../trunk/
    fi
  else
    svn co http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/
    cd Freya/Routes/
    cp wp-tests-config.php ../../trunk/
  fi
}

for f in *; do
  if [[ -d $f ]]; then
    if [[ $f != ".git" ]] && [[ $f != "bin" ]] && [[ $f != "docs" ]]; then
      cd "$f/"

      if [[ -f "routes-test" ]]; then
        wordpress_routes
        run_tests
      fi

      run_tests
    fi
  fi
done
```

Why do I have run the script twice to get phpunit to actually run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen something similar to this before.  I was having problems with sessions variables not initializing until *after* the first time it was run... then the F5-refresh allowed it to work correctly. Could that be the issue?